# Error Instance members can't be accessed from a factory constructor. Try removing the reference to the instance member

Tags: flutter

Instance members can't be accessed from a factory constructor. Try removing the reference to the instance member.

[image]

**How do you fix it?**
How should I fix it? Can anyone tell me that I have followed everything but it didn't work?

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class MyCard {
  String name;
  String desc;
  String image;
  String flav;
  double price;

  MyCard(this.name, this.desc, this.image, this.flav, this.price);
  factory MyCard.Food(name, desc, image, flav, price) =>
      MyCard(name, desc, image, flav, price);
  MyCard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        desc = json['desc'],
        image = json['image'],
        flav = json['flav'],
        price = json['price'];
}

class Food extends MyCard {
  @override
  String name;
  @override
  String desc;
  @override
  String image;
  @override
  String flav;
  @override
  double price;

  @JsonSerializable()
  Food(
      {required this.name,
      required this.desc,
      required this.image,
      required this.flav,
      required this.price})
      : super(name, desc, image, flav, price);

  Food _$FoodFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Food(
      name: json['name']as String,
      desc: json['desc']as String,
      image: json['image']as String,
      flav: json['flav']as String,
      price: json['price']as double,
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> _$FoodToJson(Food instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'name': instance.name,
      'desc': instance.desc,
      'image': instance.image,
      'flav': instance.flav,
      'price': instance.price,
    };  
  factory Food.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)=> _$FoodFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FoodToJson(this);
  /*{
        'name': name,
        'desc': desc,
        'image': image,
        'flav': flav,
        'price': price
      };*/
  static var foodList = [
    Food(
      name:'Fraise Cream',
      desc:
          'We have been loading up on the stone fruit and berries at the market. We have no self control to these summer gems. We have gross we can out of hand, our  Strawberry...',
      price: 2.50,
      image: 'assets/images/food1.png',
      flav: 'Strawberry Flovour Sweet Ice Cream',
    ),
    Food(
      name: 'Mandarine',
      desc:
          'We have been loading up on the stone fruit and berries at the market. We have no self control to these summer gems. We have gross we can out of hand, our  Strawberry...',
      price: 3.50,
      image: 'assets/images/food2.png',
      flav: 'Caramel Flovour Sweet Ice Cream',
    )
  ];
}

class Beverage extends MyCard {
  @override
  String name;
  @override
  String desc;
  @override
  String image;
  @override
  String flav;
  @override
  double price;

  Beverage(
      {required this.name,
      required this.desc,
      required this.image,
      required this.flav,
      required this.price})
      : super(name, desc, image, flav, price);

  static var beverageList = [
    Beverage(
      name: 'test',
      desc: 'We have test',
      image: 'assets/images/food1.png',
      price: 3.0,
      flav: 'Strawberry test',
    ),
  ];
}
```

I'm new to JSON and serialization. So I don't know if it's correct or not. Need advice too which if there is any mistake, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `_$FoodFromJson` static like this:

```
static Food _$FoodFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Food(
  name: json['name'] as String,
  desc: json['desc'] as String,
  image: json['image'] as String,
  flav: json['flav'] as String,
  price: json['price'] as double,
);
```

Comment: If I want to put the value in firebase into the list of variable foodList variable name what should I do when it's up now

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75125373/json-and-serialization-how-to-fetch-data-from-firebase-as-firestore-database) error static Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FoodToJson(this);  What should be? _$FoodToJson(this);